# What punishment would Jack face if he did not cooperate with the Police Chief?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), Detective Sergeant Jack is accused of hitting Ezekiel Garcia, but the Police Chief offers him a deal.
In exchange for testifying against three officers, he will be suspended from his
position in Narcotics for a brief period of time, after which he will be transferred
to Vice. Once he transfers out of Vice, he will be able to return to his show, Badge of Honor.

> Jack: Okay, **I'll do it**.
>
> POLICE CHIEF: The grand jury will hear your testimony tomorrow.

By saying ‘Okay, I’ll do it,’ Jack agrees to cooperate with the Police Chief and is ready to face suspension from his position in Narcotics for a brief period of time. But **what if he does not**?

What punishment would Jack face if he did not cooperate with the Police Chief?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure we can know for sure, its a fiction set in 1950's Los Angeles.

However I'm confident that even in the 1950's beating up a suspect was still unlawful use of force, which makes the offense '[Battery](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=242.&lawCode=PEN)'.  Today even 'simple' battery can result in [a fine and six months in prison](https://www.cmcdefense.com/california-penal-code-section-242/).

I also imagine that a convicted criminal would also lose their job in the police force, which in Vincennes case, would also result in them losing their lucrative sideline as a consultant on Badge of Honor.